# Repeated Measures Survival Analysis per ID and per latency

Tags: mixed-model, survival, repeated-measures, frailty, joint-modeling

I have chosen survival analysis and mixed effects to be analyzed in a joint model using the frailty pack. I am not sure if I am dong it right and I need more expert insights.
I am testing people's recall of 9 numbers on screen. Their status (success) is 1 if they score all 9 and 0 if they don't. I have repeated measures design where each participant does the task several times at different latencies (time variable). The issue is that the participant was tested on the same latency multiple times as well and can have a status of 1 or 0 for that latency at those different attempts. I would like to test their performance based on the language group and main strategy used to solve the task. Here is an excerpt of my design:

[image]

I have used the below code to test the effect of language group (which was significant) but I am unsure if it is accounting for ID properly. Also, I guess my data follows the counting process style of input but I am unsure how my model can factor this design in. I am copying my code and the result of the model. Please advise how to approach this data anlaysis. Keep in mind my data is not normal and I am unsure what assumptions I should take into account. I have been reading up on the frailtypack, and I am also unsure what knots and kappa to choose. Further, my model only shows the coefficient for the multilingual group, and I am unsure how to calculate the hazard ratios and how to choose the baseline value for the monolingual group. Lastly, I need help on how to visualize this data, what packages to use, etc.

Please note that all my professors and statistical consultants at my university are unfamiliar with this approach, and this is for my PhD. I want to make sure I report my results correctly.

Thanks!

**CODE**
library(frailtypack)
library(survival)
Fit the Joint Model with Frailty
joint_model <- frailtypack::frailtyPenal(Surv(latency, success) ~ Language_Group + cluster(id),
data = Data,
n.knots = 7,
kappa = 10000)

**Results**

rint(joint_model)
Call:
frailtypack::frailtyPenal(formula = Surv(latency, success) ~
Language_Group + cluster(id), data = Data, n.knots = 7, kappa = 10000)

Shared Gamma Frailty model parameter estimates
using a Penalized Likelihood on the hazard function

```
                       coef               exp(coef)          SE coef (H)         SE coef (HIH)
```

Language_Groupmultilingual "2.61123823230111" "13.6159000653275" "0.295178424093536" "0.295178424093536"
z                  p
Language_Groupmultilingual "8.84630453706082" "< 1e-16"

```
Frailty parameter, Theta: 6.6802 (SE (H): 1.18984 ) p = 9.8642e-09 

  penalized marginal log-likelihood = -867.94
  Convergence criteria: 
  parameters = 1.43e-06 likelihood = 1.06e-05 gradient = 1.33e-09 

  LCV = the approximate likelihood cross-validation criterion
        in the semi parametrical case     = 0.448002 

  n= 1888
  n events= 398  n groups= 290
  number of iterations:  13 

  Exact number of knots used:  7 
  Value of the smoothing parameter:  10000, DoF:  2.21
```